# How can I set custom icons for fancygit in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, termux, git-extensions

Is it possible to set custom fonts for a terminal extension called `fancygit`. I read through the **readme.md** file, and while it does say it supports it, I cannot find out how to access the file that stores the icon configuration, nor can I set it via terminal prompts.